# How to find the color "A" that would look exactly the same as 100% opacity color "B" when it is at 90% opacity?

Tags: color

So I have color "B" at 100% opacity.
I need a way of finding the color "A" that looks exactly the same as the above when it is at 90% opacity.

Assume that background is pure white but I don't think that matters as long as it's the same color on both instances.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Result of normal alpha blending is:

*C*<sub>out</sub> = *α* * *C*<sub>FG</sub>+(1-*α*) * *C*<sub>BG</sub>

where *C*<sub>FG</sub> is the foreground color and *C*<sub>BG</sub> is the background color and *α* is the opacity. Thus you want to solve A from equation:

*B* = 0.9 * *A* + (1-0.9) * *C*<sub>BG</sub>

Which after manipulation is:

*A* = (*B* - 0.1 * *C*<sub>BG</sub>) / 0.9

further assuming white color the formula per color channel is:

*A* = (*B* - 0.1) / 0.9

While this is the general answer, there is a **big caveat** associated with this calculation. This does not account for any color management. So you might need to convert the color to linear and then back to the original color space to do this calculation. There is also a second consideration to think about: The color you may need to use can exit the displayable gamut of your system.

Comment: What's that in English?

Comment: @TheGeorgeL which part?

Comment: Well let's say that for some crazy reason you're only able to work in hex colours,  how would that be found from this math?

Comment: Extract the hex value of one color channel as a number, then you divide your hex color by 255 use formulas to calculate and multiply by result 255 convert back to hex. repeat for 2 other channels.

Comment: Ooh, that's far simpler than I expected.

Comment: @joojaa I've tried your technique several times, and still can't get it right. Could you add a specific example please?  I have the color rgb(112, 166, 185) at 100% opacity. I'm looking for a new color that's identical to that when the new color is at 50% opacity and on a white background.

Comment: That color combination is not possible @Nocturno ! if you add 128 to any positive number Its sill above 112. Atleast unless your space and calculation does not account for nonlinearity in which case i need to know colorspaces too. Anyway not all combinations are possible.

Comment: @joojaa You're right. That color combination is not possible at 50% opacity. But I was able able to graph the three equations and saw that the combination becomes possible at 57% opacity. The final combination is rgba(4, 99, 132, .57), which when placed over a white background displays as rgb(112, 166, 185). Thanks for the help!